# bundle install mongoid, mongoid_ext error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

I get this error when I run `bundle install` to install Shapado. What does it mean? and how to fix it?

> Could not find gem 'mongoid (~> 3) ruby', which is required by gem 'mongoid_ext (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: My Gemfile is the same in shapado i just comment the twiter line.
i thing the Gemfile having this rule is here
https://github.com/dcu/mongoid_ext/blob/master/Gemfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot provide exact answers unless you show us your `Gemfile`. In the meantime, you can try to

- Check your `Gemfile` for typos (missing commas, additional spaces inside the gem names)
- Delete `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again

When i download [the latest version of shapado](https://github.com/ricodigo/shapado/tree/9e1bcf31ae1b4083a3b71ec21d92eadd11175e1b) and try to `bundle install` i get a similar error, but for the `twitter` gem:

```
Could not find twitter-1.7.2 in any of the sources
```

It seems Shapado is a bit out of date and has not seen any commits for quite a while…